# oTrying to upload audio file locally using its blob url

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I have a task to record audio and store it on server. Right now, I am using local python server to run the code. I am getting the blob url of the audio file but when I am calling following javascript function to store it it is giving error:-

```
  function upload(blob) {
  var xhr;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhr.open('GET', 'upload.php',true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {  };

  // Listen to the upload progress.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');

  var data= new FormData(this);
  data.append('file',blob);
  //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","Blob");
  xhr.send(data);
};
```

my upload.php which is on server side

```
   <?php

    if(isset($_FILES["file"])) {

        $f = $_FILES["file"];
        $dir = "data";

        if(!file_exists($dir))
            mkdir($dir);

        foreach($f["name"] as $k => $name) {

            $file = $dir."/".$name;

            if($f["error"][$k] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($f["tmp_name"][$k], $file)) {
                $uploaded[] = $file;
            }

        }

        die(json_encode($uploaded));        
    }

?>
```

Comment: `blob` needs to be a Blob not a Blob Url

Comment: @Musa Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you explain?

Comment: A blob url is just a string something like `blob://http%3A//example.com`, its not the data, the blob is the data which is something different from a blob url.

Comment: Got it. Now, I am doing like this-->
    var data= new FormData();
     data.append('file',blob);
     xhr.send(data);

Now there is no error but in downloads it is showing "output.wav (Failed-No file)"